# Finding the big O of $f(n) = 36585n^6 + \pi n^3 - \sin(n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I need to find the Big O of the given function. However I am struggling with figuring out my C and $N_0$.

$$f(n) = 36585n^6 + \pi n^3 - \sin(n)$$

Can I write it out as:

$$36000n^6 \le 36585n^6 +\pi n^3 - \sin(n) \le 37000n^6 $$

Where I would us $36000$ as $c_1$ and $n^6$ as $g(n)$, and $37000$ as $c_2$ with $n^6$ as $g(n)$.

and say:

$$ f(n)= \mathcal{O}  (n^6) $$

Or am I completely missing the mark?

The book we're using for Discrete Structures is not the best, so any guidance on a general way to find C and $n_0$ would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a constant $C$ and number $N$ such that $f(n) \le C n^6$ for $n \ge N$.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(n) \theta g(n^6)$? Wasn't $g(n)=n^6$? Do you mean $=\mathcal{O}$ in place of $\theta$?

Comment: @Gary Yes. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that: $|\sin n|\le n^6$ for $n\ge 1$ 
$\pi n^3\le n^6$ for $n\ge 2$

So for $n\ge 2$, we have: $|f(n)| \le 36585n^6 + (\pi)n^3 +|\sin(n)|\le 36585n^6+n^6+n^6=36587n^6\implies f(n)=\mathcal O(n^6)$